# How to export a resolved promise and import it again

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, apollo, apollo-server

I would like to export the `ApolloServer` function to be imported later in a test suite or simply within the `index.ts` file.

Working code:

```
  // src/index.ts
;(async () => {
  const app = express()

  await createConnections()

  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema: await buildSchema({
      resolvers: [HelloWorldResolver, MovieResolver],
    }),
    context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }),
  })

  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false })

  app
    .listen({ port: ENVIRONMENT.port, host: ENVIRONMENT.host }, () => {
      console.log(
        `Server ready at http://${ENVIRONMENT.host}:${ENVIRONMENT.port}/graphql`
      )
    })
    .on('error', function (error) {
      console.log(`Failed starting server: ${error}`)
    })
})()
```

I tried to extract this to a separate file:

```
// src/apolloServer.ts
export const apolloServer = (async () => {
  return new ApolloServer({
    schema: await buildSchema({
      resolvers: [HelloWorldResolver, MovieResolver],
    }),
    context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }),
  })
})()
```

And consume it:

```
// src/index.ts
import { apolloServer } from './apolloServer'
apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false })
```

The error thrown is:

> (node:13848) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: apolloServer_1.apolloServer.applyMiddleware is not a function

How is it possible to export and import this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

build a function to generate brand new ApolloServer instance.
run the function anywhere else to generate a brand new ApolloServer

```
// src/apolloServer.ts
export const getApolloServer = async () => {
  return new ApolloServer({
    schema: await buildSchema({
      resolvers: [HelloWorldResolver, MovieResolver],
    }),
    context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }),
  })
}
```

```
// src/index.ts
import { getApolloServer } from './apolloServer'
const clonedServer = await getApolloServer();
clonedServer.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false })
```

Answer (score 1):

In your extracted version, you did not define `apolloServer` as an instance of  `ApolloServer`, but as the result of running an `async` function. As `async` functions always return a Promise object, `apolloServer` is now a Promise object.

You should get the value to which it resolves, either with `then` or `await`.

In your first code version you were surely running within the context of an `async` function, while in the second version the `import` part happens outside of an `async` function. You should just repeat the `async` pattern there also:

```
import { apolloServer } from './apolloServer'
(async () => {
    (await apolloServer).applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false })
})();
```

Comment: I've updated the OP. The issue is that `buildSchema` returns a Promise. So we need to wait for it anyhow. How would you extract the `ApolloServer` code from the index file?

Comment: See addition to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think it should probably be `await apolloServer()`

Comment: It only needs to be executed if you change the imported script, like in the other answer was done. But in your question, you executed it in the imported script with the additional `()` after the `async` expression. So taking your question as it stands, you get a promise from it, and it should not have `()` here. A promise is not a function.